# Disable image resizing on specific upload fields

Tags: theme-options, images, uploads

I am using the [Options Framework Theme](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/) from devinsays, but am having a "small" problem with the Image Upload functionality. Basically, I need to disable resizing on a specific upload-field, but keep it on all others.

I do realize that this functionality is not specifically dependent on this framework, but I haven't been able to find any resource on how to achieve this on a case by case basis for specific Theme Options, so I'm hoping someone here could help.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress will always create the additional images for "thumbnail", "medium" and "large" sizes.  The options panel doesn't add an additional size- it just resizes the one you've selected using CSS.

If you want to override that CSS you can hook in an additional stylesheet that will override the id on that option.

Comment: I have already gotten rid of the default sizes, and replaced them with the necessary ones. The problem, however, is that one specific upload field needs to not be handled by `wp_handle_upload` - but just upload the file and not resize it - as it should retain its original size. So it's not really a CSS problem at this level, but finding a way to override the default upload-system.

Comment: wordpress , if not asked by the theme functions, will always keep also the original size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to do this "per upload field", but if you use a plugin like [Dynamic Image Resizer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/) they are only generated (resized/resampled) when they are called on the front-end. Thanks!